# How to extend the template context in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

How can I add new keys to the context that is provided for templates (i.e. [Macro](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html?highlight=user_defined_macros))? I have looked in the source code for solution, but could not find out myself.

I have to adapt to external constraints in naming the template parameters (`start_date` and `end_date`). [`user_defined_macros` and `user_defined_filters`](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html?highlight=user_defined_macros) and [plugin macros](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html?highlight=macros) are not applicable, because these will provide functions, not the evaluated values to be substituted (i.e `{{start_date()}}` instead of `{{start_date}}` must be written in the template).
I have tried to use [Jinja's `contextfunction` decorator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/?highlight=contextfunction#jinja2.contextfunction), but context can't be modified.

The `get_template_context()` method of `TaskInstance` class returns the dictionary in [models/taskinstance.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1600), which becomes the context for templating. It seems that, there's no way to extend (update()) this dictionary by other means other than patching the source of Airflow, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: can you give a code example that will explain what you want to do ?

Comment: For example q1.sql file would containt the following query:
`select * from table1 where created between "{{start_date}}" and "{{end_date}}"`
The contents of q1.sql is given, I can't change it.
I have to pass `start_date` and `end_date` parameters. It's trivial task to do with vanilla Jinja2. I could not render it in advance, because task_instance/execution_date will only be available on execution.

Comment: So you want to pass user values called start_date & end_date to be rendered in the task but you don't want to comply with the Airflow convention ? May I ask what prevents you to read the SQL file and modify it to met with the requirements of user defined macro?

Comment: I have a client and a custom legacy system to backfill these queries as Airflow 1.x is quiet slow in scheduling these for each day. Of course there could be multiple solutions, but then we would solve a different problem in this question. I could rewrite the legacy system to support Airflow fashioned templating, and complicate things for both systems (i.e. apply functions instead of simple variables to support range queries). I'm getting inclined to patch Airflow, and add a `user_defined_vars` to extend context in a clean manner, where callable vars will be evaluated beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

you can use out of the box templating for sql files. For example you can use:

```
select * from table1 where created between "{{params.start_date}}" and "{{params.end_date}}"
```

and give the parameters in your task definition:

```
task = PostgresOperator(task_id='task_name',
                               sql="sql/delete_and_copy.sql",
                               postgres_conn_id="postgres_connection",
                               database="dev",
                               params={
                                          'start_date': start_date,
                                          'end_date': end_date,
                                      },
                                      )
```

start_date and end_date can be calculated by a Python operator.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I should insert a task in the beginning of every workflow/DAG which pushes start_date/end_date into XCom and pull it from this task? Or there are other means to pass values between 2 consequent tasks that I'm not aware of?

start_date and end_date should be calculated from execution_date of task instance. The goal would be to keep the template intact and use `{{start_date}}` and `{{end_date}}` as other programs are also using these templates.